# my model is not showing up in admin model data is getting visble in link bar in csrf middle ware token

Tags: django, python-3.x, visual-studio, django-models, django-templates

```html
{% block body %} 
{% load static %}
<div class="container my-3">
    <h3>Contact Us</h3>
    <form action="/contact" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name='name' placeholder="Enter Your Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name='email' placeholder="Enter Your Email">
  </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Phone</label>
    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" name='phone' placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number">
  </div>


   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="desc">Your requirements:-</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="desc" name='desc' rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Contact</button>
</form>
</div>
```

```
    def index(request):
    return render(request, 'prop/home.html')
def contact(request):

    if request.method=='POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        phone = request.POST['phone']
        desc = request.POST['desc']
        contact=Contact(name=name,email=email,phone=phone,desc=desc)
        contact.save()
      return render(request, 'prop/contact.html')
```

result
 "GET /prop/contact/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=npxCzACid026bcA0bYugZdAL1K2Ondqu2EtpzTuoDbnYivut9tsHJnh5Tq7NWOdU&name=yashi&email=hyashkzo%40gmail.com&phone=55645blbb&desc= HTTP/1.1" 200 8758

Comment: show us your template

Comment: yeah wait i  am posting it

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing exactly, please formulate a proper question where you explain what you're trying to achieve, what you are actually doing to test the behavior (e.g. I open this url, then fill in the form, then submit it, it should go to this url, etc...).

Comment: Also if the first line of your view `contact` is `return render(...)` then why are you expecting it to do anything else than rendering the template? Is this really your code? Anything after your `return` statement is never executed.

Comment: i just wana sumbit my form and get it in my database in admin in my models but when hit the press button it don't show up in admin pannel and it get visible in command line and link bar as this :-result "GET /prop/contact/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=npxCzACid026bcA0bYugZdAL1K2Ondqu2EtpzTuoDbnYivut9tsHJnh5Tq7NWOdU&name=yashi&email=hyashkzo%40gmail.com&phone=55645blbb&desc= HTTP/1.1" 200 8758 and i have corrected that render mistake still it is not working same issue i am facing

Comment: @dirkgroten i have corrected my render mistake still facing same issue can you help me out with it please

Comment: Is the code of the template really what you have? It’s not possible that a form with action=“/contact” gets submitted to /prop/contact. Please check your <form> tag and show it here exactly as it is in your HTML source. We’re talking about the home.html template right?

Comment: @dirkgroten no this is my contact template home one is different

Comment: That’s why you need to write a proper question. **Explain** what you are doing not just show code. Why are you showing the index view if it’s not relevant to the question? Anyway, the code in the template you’re showing cannot produce the behavior you’re describing (a GET request to /prop/contact). Rephrase your question, show us the exact code and explain what’s happening.

Comment: @dirkgroten basically i made a contact form with a sumbit button i want that when i press the sumbit button than my whole form get sumbit to the model in my admin pannel but when i hit sumbit it do not show up in admin model

Comment: @dirkgroten it show up in my url and visual studio code as

Comment: Yes that I understand. But when I ask explain I mean something like this: I go to this url in the browser. I see this message in the django console.  It renders the form in the browser. This is the html source code I see when I look at the browser source in the debugger. This is the button I press to submit. This is the request shown in the network tab of my browser debugger. In the django runserver console this is what I see. Etc... that’s how you’re supposed to **explain** what’s going on.

Comment: @dirkgroten when i runserver fill my form and sumbit my data dont show up in admin model i can see my data in wired manner in csrfmiddlewaretoken

Comment: Please read my previous comment and do as I told. You’ve already told us that when you submit your form you don’t see the result in admin. Do what I told you to do. It’s called “debugging”.

Answer (score 0):

make following changes and try

```
<form action="{% url 'contact' %}" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
```

instead of button

```
<input type="submit" value="Contact" class="btn btn-success">
```

Provided you have a url with name contact

Comment: stil facing same issue